# Stored Procedure to return/result a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I just started working/learning store procedures. I'm just wondering if it's possible for a Store Procedure to return a string.

Right now the store procedure that i'm working on takes one parameter (customer #) and returns two fields- vehicle # and ETA. I'm just wondering if this could be put on a string like "Your vehicle # is 1234 with ETA in 10 minutes." or some kind of a message if no value is returned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is certainly possible - though accessing this data will depend on both the version of sql you are using (e.g. mysql, sql server) and upon the technology that you are using the access that data (e.g. ado.net). Add that information and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: What database? Stored procedure syntax varies between different RDBMSs.

Comment: Thanks guys. It's MS SQL server.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetVehicleInfo 
@CustId INT 
OUTPUT AS

  RETURN (SELECT 'Your vehicle # is ' + id + ' with ETA in ' + ETA + ' minutes' 
          FROM YourTable WHERE CustId = @CustId )

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, once I was returning a full link :) In MSSQL for instance, you might first declare a result table in the procedure and at the end of the procedure you can do the following statement:

```
SELECT 'whatever string you want to put' + columnName + ' whatever...' FROM @result
```

Where @result is the declared table

Edit: case where the columnName type is INT you can use the CONVERT function. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Sql server, it is as simple as the below code:

```
select 'Your vehicle # is ' + vehiclenum + ' with ETA in ' eta ' minutes' from table_1
where your_select_criteria
```

In that sql vehiclenum and eta are both column names from table_1 but you can equally do a join in this query.

If vehiclenum is an int then you need to convert it using the convert function like so:

```
select 'Your vehicle # is ' + convert(varchar(10), vehiclenum) + ' with ETA in ' eta ' minutes' 
from table_1
where your_select_criteria
```

The last piece of the puzzle is getting the value out into code. As it is, this will return a record set.

Using the SqlClient you would use the ExecuteScalar method as describe [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).

```
var outputText = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```